# Values have been retrieved from Firebase, but cannot map onto resources (Xamarin Android)

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

I am trying to retrieve values according to the value passed from another activity on Xamarin Android. I have successfully retrieved the data accordingly and it now sits in my model class variables. The problem is, I cannot map the values onto the resources variables(I have bind the resource Id with variables). It states that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". From what I understand, I was trying to map values onto non existing object. I dont know how to fix this...

p/s I am a beginner in Xamarin Android. Any kind of help is appreciated.

here is excerpt of my model class

'''

```
public class Questions
    {
        public string answer1 { get; set; }
        public string answer2 { get; set; }
        public string answer3 { get; set; }
.......
```

'''

here is my listener in activity, to grab the values in firebase and map it accordingly to my model class
'''

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.Exists())
                {
                    Questions qs = new Questions();
                    var obj = snapshot.Children;
                    foreach (DataSnapshot quest in obj.ToEnumerable())
                    {
                        qs.qid = quest.Key;
                        qs.question = quest.Child("question").Value.ToString();
                        qs.answer1 = quest.Child("answer1").Value.ToString();
                        qs.answer2 = quest.Child("answer2").Value.ToString();
                        qs.answer3 = quest.Child("answer3").Value.ToString();
                        qs.correctanswer = quest.Child("correctanswer").Value.ToString();
}
```

'''

and here is where i try to map the value. in the activity class as well.
'''

```
 private void GetData(Questions qs)
        {
            **this.TxtQs.Text** = qs.question;
            **this.answer1.Text** = qs.answer1;
            **this.answer2.Text** = qs.answer2;
            **this.answer3.Text** = qs.answer3;
```

}
'''
Here is where I bind the resources IDs with the variable(that will be put values into at GetData()).
'''

```
public class kuizActivity2 : BaseActivity, IQuestionsView 
    {
        #region Declare element view
        [BindView(Resource.Id.soalan)]
        public TextView TxtQs { get; set; }


        [BindView(Resource.Id.choice_a_radio)]
        public Button answer1 { get; set; }
            
        [BindView(Resource.Id.choice_b_radio)]
        public Button answer2 { get; set; }

        [BindView(Resource.Id.choice_c_radio)]
        public Button answer3 { get; set; }
```

....'''

I called GetData(qs) from my OnCreate(). In BOLD is where the error is. I debug it and found out it is all null. here's a picture of my debug

[debug bold lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3qlH.jpg)

Comment: All your Widgets seem to be null. Did you call FindViewById to get them from your layout?

Comment: I already bind the resources together with the variable that will be used. I have modified the question and add the code for your review.. 

My take is I know that I tried to put values into non-existing object, but when I tried creating the object on onCreate(), it wont pass the created object to class GetData().

Comment: Well the issue is you either call GetData _before_ your widgest are initialized, or they are simply not found. Hard to tell without more context on where GetData is called and where the Widgets are found.

Comment: I already able to solve it! Updating this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE SOLVED!

Apparently, I tried to call something that hasnt been initialized yet, eventhough I am a little bit confused on the Cheeseknife(Bind) function.

I made the binding variable as static and then called them again on oncreate(). rather than calling GetData(); on oncreate(), i called them from my listener. It got called right away without any null values!

However, I still have issues that the listener doesnt get detach after it retrieves the first value. It still passes the value to GetData() but then go back to listener method and do the same till it reads all value from firebase. So the GetData() got overwrite till the last value, only then it comes out on the resources(on phone screen).